# Why this expressions are not equivalent?

Tags: python, class, runtime-error

As a homework I must code in python a binary tree on which I can perform simple operations and later print the expression in reverse Polish notation. My original answer was mostly correct, by in the end, the last function `post_fix()` was giving me the error `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'left'`. This was my original answer:

```py
class N:
    "un noeud de l'arbre"
    def __init__(self, c, l=None, r=None):
        self.content = c
        self.left = l
        self.right = r

    def print_tree(self):
        if self.left is not None:
            self.left.print_tree()         
        print(self.content) 
        if self.right is not None:   
            self.right.print_tree()

expression_1 = N('*', N('+', N(7), N(3)), N(4))
expression_2 = N('+', N(7), N('*', N(3), N(4)))

def isnumber(s):
    try:
        float(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

def calcule(x, oper, y):
    "applique l'operateur à x et y et retourne le résultat"
    if isnumber(x) and isnumber(y):
        if oper == '+':
            return x + y
        elif oper == '-':
            return x - y
        if oper == '*':
            return x * y
        elif oper == '/':
            return x / y
        else: 
            print('\033[1;31mERROR: "{}" is not a valid operator.\033[1;m'.format(oper))
            return None
    else: 
        print ('\033[1;31mERROR: operands must be numerical values.\033[1;m')

def evalue(arbre):
    "evalue l'expression logée dans l'arbre"
    if type(arbre.content) in (float, int):
        return arbre.content
    else:
        operator = arbre.content
        vg = evalue(arbre.left)
        vd = evalue(arbre.right)
        return calcule(vg, operator, vd)

def post_fix(arbre):
    "retourne l'expression de cet arbre en notation post-fixée"
    pf = ''
    if arbre.left is not None :
        pf = pf + post_fix(arbre.left) + ' '
    if arbre.right is not None :
        pf = pf + post_fix(arbre.right) + ' '
    return pf + arbre.content

print('Expression 1 en notation post-fix:', post_fix(expression_1))  
print('Expression 2 en notation post-fix:', post_fix(expression_2))
```

The correct correct way of defining `post_fix()` was given:

```py
def post_fix(arbre):
    "retourne l'expression de cet arbre en notation post-fixée"
    pf = str()
    if arbre.left is not None :
        pf = pf + post_fix(arbre.left) + ' '
    if arbre.right is not None :
        pf = pf + post_fix(arbre.right) + ' '
    return pf + str(arbre.content)
```

Could someone tell me the difference between both, and the reason why my original declaration led to an error? Thank you in advance.

EDIT:
I've noted, following the accepted answer, that the main problem was a type incompatibility, nevertheless, the question stays open: the error given was `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'left'`. I was using Jupyter.

Comment: Next time, try to write all the variables in english, so that everyone in the community can help efficiently.

Comment: You cannot concatenate a string to an integer, you need to convert the integer to a string in order to do that @toridoverdejo

Comment: The error you are getting is probably due to the fact that you have a `None` coming in the `post_fix` function at some point rather than the concatenation of a string and an integer (although a source of error as well). We would have to see the whole traceback + the code producing that error to help more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually get the error as follows when I run your code

```
return pf + arbre.content
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

Which tells you that you cannot concatenate a `int` and a `str`, hence the first approach won't work, but you can concatenate them after converting the `int` to an `str`, which is what we do in the second approach

```
In [16]: x = 'a'   

In [17]: y = 2                                                                                                                 

In [18]: x+y                                                                                                                   
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-259706549f3d> in <module>
----> 1 x+y

TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

In [19]: x+str(y)                                                                                                              
Out[19]: 'a2'
```

As you can see, concatenating a string and an integer threw an error, but no such error was thrown when you converted string to integer and then concatenated, which is what happens in your first and second way of `post_fix` respectively

Comment: The error I was given was ```'NoneType' object has no attribute 'left'```, not about concatenation. Why?